# Why is my WSL2 enviornment referencing Java folder outside its virtual environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I start my development rails server I get this following message first.  To my knowledge WSL2 is a virtual environment.

I would have expected it to now reference a Java directory that resides on my Windows host.  Is this likely something I carried over in the project from when I was using WSL1?  How would I safely correct this?

```
/home/daveomcd/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath 
in PATH, mode 040777
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that this was an old question when I answered it.  Looks like it just got bumped because of the other late answer.  Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem when trying to fix the slowness of WSL2. The recommended solution was to move the files from the mounted NTFS drive to the root ext4 filesystem (using `\\$wsl\<distroname>`), so I did that.

I set up `/etc/wsl.conf` as below:

```
# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,umask=0033"
mountFsTab = false
[interop]
enabled = true
appendWindowsPath = true
```

And ran `rails bundle` to update dependencies.

Also make sure that your file permissions and owner settings are updated. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you rephrase that a bit to make it read more like an *answer*?  It reads like a comment right now, describing what you think the *problem* is, but not really providing a solution.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds did that. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Looks much better - Thanks!

Comment: Some thoughts - The only real "non-default" option in your `/etc/wsl.conf` is the `options` line for adding metadata support, which *could* be a fix, since it allows the WSL instance to "pretend to" manage permissions for files on the NTFS drives. But you mentioned in your previous answer that this wasn't working for you. This could be because there is a typo on the `options` line. `unmask` should be `umask`.  If you fix that, the rest of the `[automount]` section isn't even needed, since the other defaults will start working again.  With the typo, the `metadata` wasn't working at all, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'd love to make this more of a comment to see if I'm on the right track before committing to an answer.  However, since there's too much info here for that, I'll make an *attempt* at getting you an answer here.

While it is a virtual environment, by default WSL provides several "Windows Interop" features that allow it to:

1. automatically mount Windows drives in `/mnt/{c,d,...}`
2. append the Windows path to the Linux path
3. run Windows executables inside Linux
4. share Windows environment variables with Linux (although this is not something that happens by default)

I can't be sure (long, long time since I've used Rails), but it looks like something in the `app_loader.rb` is checking permissions on Java directories in the path.  It may be using some logic like *"check each path entry and look for a `java` or `java.exe` there.  If found, check permissions."*  Or something like that.  That means that (2) and (3) above may be confusing it.

You can see this in action with `which java.exe`, which will likely return a Windows path.  Or run `notepad.exe`, which will launch the Windows Notepad executable from within Linux/WSL (magic! ).

These are both *very* useful features, so I hate to disable them completely, but it's the easiest way to figure out if that's the problem.  Create a `/etc/wsl.conf` with the following [contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#interop):

```
[interop]
enabled=false
appendWindowsPath=false
```

Exit your WSL instance and then:

- (from PowerShell, CMD, or Windows Start) Run `wsl --list --verbose` to see the name of your distribution (most likely `Ubuntu`)
- Likewise, run `wsl --terminate <distro>` to terminate that distribution.
- Restart your WSL instance
- Try running `/mnt/c/Windows/system32/notepad.exe` (assuming a normal `C:\Windows` installation) (should fail, since interop is disabled)
- Try `which notepad.exe` (should fail, since the Windows path should no longer be appended to the Linux path)
- Try to start your Rails dev server again - Might work (might not, I could easily be wrong about the root-cause here)

If it does work, then you can try to correct the situation with several less invasive methods than disabling those features entirely:

- If you plan on only using WSL for your development, then you could remove the Windows JDK.
- Or at least remove the Windows JDK from the PATH in Windows.
- Or, if you want to keep it installed and in the Windows path, you could have a shell startup file (e.g. `.bashrc`) that removes it from the path only in WSL.  I'll point you to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108873/removing-a-directory-from-path) which contains multiple techniques for doing so.
- Or you could keep the `appendWindowsPath=false` in your `/etc/wsl.conf` but then add back in the paths you want manually in your startup config.